# Why the combination of decltype and is_same gives wrong result?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, decltype

I have the following function:

```
template<typename T> auto print_type_info(const T& t) {  // C++17
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
        return t + 1;    // int case
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(t), double&>::value) {
        return t + 0.1;    // double case
    } else {
        return t;    // other case
    }
}
void main() {
    assert(print_type_info(1) == 2);      // int test
    assert(print_type_info(0.1) == 0.2);  // double test
    assert(print_type_info("0") == "0");  // char* test
}
```

Runing the above assert tests in VSCode:

- int test goes into the int case correctly.
- double test goes into the other case wrongly in run-time.
- char* case goes into the double case wrongly in compile-time case.

I have made the following changes for the double case all with the same result:

- double&
- dobule
- const double
- const double&

Why is this?

Comment: The correct type is `const double &`. How did you determine "goes into ... case in runtime/compile-time"? Also `==` won't give you the right result when comparing pointers like this, use `strcmp` or `string_view`.

Comment: Beware floating-point arithmetic – `0.1 + 0.1` isn't necessarily equal to `0.2`.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/jxnTMP3qT

Comment: What makes you think that any of the conditions get evaluated at runtime?

Comment: Point was to show types involved. It is easier to print those types names in runtime then at compile time. In general it is recommended to create test for constexpresion which are evaluated at compile time (to prove they work during compilation) and at run time for easy debugging.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by HolyBlackCat, the correct answer is:

```
template<typename T> auto print_type_info(const T& t) {  // C++17
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
        return t + 1;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(t), const double&>::value) {
        return t + 0.1;
    } else {
        return t;
    }
}
```